# Retry once using functional interface

Tags: java, asynchronous, functional-programming, java-8, functional-interface

I'm new to functional programming (and Java) and I want to create something nice using it, but cannot figure out how.

I'm using BiConsumer (java.util.function.BiConsumer) for calls to the server.

I'm trying to write a code which send some request to server with existing data (calling Public createSomeTask()), only if it fails, the connector will perform a retry only once.

The code is async, Private createSomeTask() calls updateTaskStage() as well.

The problem is that I have many calls in the connector (many createSomeTask())
with current implementation, the code not looks good and I'm sure there is a way to do it better using Functional interfaces or extending the BiConsumer or any other nice way in Java 8 lile , reflection, method invoke etc.

See the code below.
I hope someone can help me with that.

```
//Main
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Connector connector = new Connector();
        connector.createSomeTask("started",(response, error)->{
        });
    }
}

//Connector Class
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;

public class Connector {
    static String taskStage = null;

    public void createSomeTask(final String taskName,
                               final BiConsumer<ServerResponse, ServerError> consumer) {
        createSomeTask(taskName, true, consumer);
    }

    private void createSomeTask(final String taskName,
                                boolean retry,
                                final BiConsumer<ServerResponse, ServerError> consumer) {
        updateTaskStage((newStage, error)->{
            if(error!=null) {
                if (retry) {
                    createSomeTask(taskName, false, consumer); //The 'recursive' retry call
                    return;
                } else {
                    consumer.accept(null, error);//only after second failure
                    return;
                }
            }
            consumer.accept(new ServerResponse(),null);
        });

    }

    //re-uses existing task or starting a new one when the current is null / failed
    private void updateTaskStage(final BiConsumer<String, ServerError> consumer) {
        if(taskStage ==null || taskStage != "failed")
            consumer.accept(taskStage,null);
        else
        {
            taskStage = "started";
            consumer.accept(taskStage,null);
        }
    }

    class ServerResponse{}
    class ServerError{}
}
```

Comment: Your code is already using BiConsumer (functional interface), lambda expressions so what else you would like to do. If you are looking for some asynchronous solution, I would suggest to explore CompletableFuture

Comment: Yes, but the problem here is the ugly recursion call with the "retry" parameter set to true or false.
I'm looking for a way maybe to extend the BiConsumer to add maybe the first consumer as a field which will be automatically invoked

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to check the `retry` flag in the consumer, as you can compose a function doing the right thing before passing it to `updateTaskStage`:

```
private void createSomeTask(
    String taskName, boolean retry, BiConsumer<ServerResponse, ServerError> consumer) {

    BiConsumer<String, ServerError> direct
        = (s, e) -> consumer.accept(e==null? new ServerResponse(): null, e);

    BiConsumer<String, ServerError> actual = retry?
        (string, error) -> {
            if(error!=null) updateTaskStage(direct); else direct.accept(string, null);
        }:
        direct;

    updateTaskStage(actual);
}
```

First, a function is created passing a translation of the back-end’s response to the provided consumer.

Then, only if `retry` is `true`, the function is composed with another function which will do a second try in the error case. For the second attempt, the direct function can be passed to `updateTaskStage`, removing the need for recursion.

As it seems that the `retry` parameter wasn’t supposed to be an option, but only part of your attempt of solving the problem, you can now get rid of it, when always performing one retry is intended:

```
public void createSomeTask(
    String taskName, BiConsumer<ServerResponse, ServerError> consumer) {

    BiConsumer<String, ServerError> direct
        = (s, e) -> consumer.accept(e==null? new ServerResponse(): null, e);

    BiConsumer<String, ServerError> actual=
        (string, error) -> {
            if(error!=null) updateTaskStage(direct); else direct.accept(string, null);
        };

    updateTaskStage(actual);
}
```